# How to rewrite all requests to index.php and sitemap.xml to sitemap.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help, I have already been doing for 2 days and all in vain...

This code works well for rewriting directories and pages to one index.php page

```
    DirectoryIndex /index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^/sitemap.xml sitemap.php [L]
```

The problem with sitemap.xml as it has to be rewritten into sitemap.php rather than into index.php

Comment: Yep, @Jonathan, I think that you should post it as an answer.

Comment: moved to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put the sitemap rule before the index rule. Rules are processed from top to bottom and once it hits the index rule (because `.*` would match `sitemap.xml`), it would stop processing further because of the `[L]` flag.

Another option would be to just use php and inside `index.php`, `include sitemap.php;` when `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` equals `sitemap.xml`. Same result.